# VariationalD of Nested Integral

Tags: syntax, variational-calculus

I am trying to calculate the variational derivative with respect to f of the the nested integral below

$$ \mathcal{J}\left[f(x) \right] = \int\limits_a^b \text{d} x \,e^{-f(x)} \int\limits_a^x \text{d}y\, e^{f(y)} $$

However, $\text{VariationalD}[\mathcal{J}, f[x], x]]$  does not seem to notice $f(y)$, but - I think - only differentiates $f(x)$.
The result it spits out is
$$-e^{-f(x)} \int\limits_a^x \text{d} y\, e^{f(y)}  $$

How can I tell $\text{VariationalD}$ to differentiate for all f's occurring in the expression? Thanks a lot.

EDIT: The code I used was

```
VariationalD[Exp[-f[x]]*Integrate[Exp[f[y]], {y, 0, x}], f[x], x]
```

Comment: Really, we need the code that you used in order to tell what went wrong...

Answer (score 1):

The reply is based on this link and some experience I have from my own projects. 
[Variational Methods](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/VariationalMethods/ref/VariationalD.html)

You practically want to perform the third example they give. You have to keep in mind that all functions should be functions of the same coordinates. Let me demonstrate with a correct and a wrong example.

The thing I would do, is to say $f(x)=f(x,y)$ and $f(y)=g(x,y)$ and then you can use this.

```
Needs["VariationalMethods`"];
VariationalD[Exp[f[x, y]] Exp[g[x, y]], {f[x, y], g[x, y]}, {x, y}]
```

The result is

```
{e^(f[x, y] + g[x, y]), e^(f[x, y] + g[x, y])}
```

As you can see, you get a list of variational derivatives.

Of course in the end, you keep in mind that you will eliminate the redundant coordinate.

If you try to perform for instance,

```
Needs["VariationalMethods`"];
VariationalD[Exp[f[x]] Exp[g[y]], {f[x], g[y]}, {x, y}]
```

Then you will only get an error message.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!!!